# I want stackoverflow to add a new feature written following

Tags: feature-request, comments

I searched at google,

**site : stackoverflow.com "mysql is deprecated "** and got 42 results and this line in google,

**In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 42 already displayed. If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.**

When i click repeat the search with the omitted results included and I got About 944 results.

Conclusion , so many people adding this comment at stackoverflow,  I think there is need to auto add these line at stackoverflow. When someone ask mysql, not mysqli, auto add this line as comment.

Benefits:

- People don't have to type such lines again and again.
- Reduces noise of these comment. It will be in good language and same in all question.

Comment: What comment?  This request doesn't make much sense in my opinion..  could you clarify?

Comment: When people ask a question tagged with "mysql" add a notice saying "mysql is deprecated"?

Comment: I don't mean tagged mysql, i mean space mysql space, some regex that searches such pattern in question. Not while selecting mysql tag

Comment: Anyway, this is suggestion, accepting or not accepting depends on stackoverflow. It has positive and negative effects. I know stackoverflow will take right decision. I just want to pay attention on this point.

Comment: @web2students.com This has been asked before as I pointed out to you in PHP chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=9919391#9919391), [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=9919369#9919369) and [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9919398#9919398)

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it would be a good idea to add this message to every posts a question including the word mysql_. I even asked some questions myself on SO where I was still using mysql_ but I also mention that I knew it was deprecated. It would be useless to have double messages that say the same.

Also in the [mysql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) it already says that mysql_ is deprecated:

#### Deprecation of mysql_ functions

> PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this sounds like an issue with negligible effect on the website.
944 results is extremely small proportion of questions and I do not believe one comment is really an issue.

However perhaps adding "mysql is deprecated" to the tag description would be a simple option.

Comment: There is no tag for the `mysql_*` PHP functions...and it's not appropriate to add it to `[mysql]` or `[PHP]`.

Comment: it's just a phrase, i can search in different way, i used "mysql is deprecated" which means exact search in google. new search on google, site : stackoverflow.com mysql is deprecated returns About 810,000 results. and again some people can write in different way, it will not return in this search.

Comment: @demonbobby I see, so the issue is relevant only to a subset of sql commands. That makes the issue even less broad that I gathered.
But as Daavan pointed out, looks like it's already on the MySql tag.

Comment: @Amicable: It's only applicable to a subset of PHP, not SQL.